# What is seasonality in PROC AUTOREG Durbin Watson Test in SAS?

Tags: time-series, correlation, seasonality, sas

I want to understand how seasonality for the Durbin Watson Test is defined. If I understand it correctly, the option DW is used for the number of seasons in my data. How can I generally check how many seasons there are? This is my plotted data (but I want to understand how it works for other data, too):
[image: "Tag" = Day, "Mittelwert" = Average Temperature]

This is where I got my information from: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.4/etsug/etsug_autoreg_gettingstarted07.htm

My data consists of average air temperature per day.

Why do I even need higher-order statistics?

Comment: The Durban-Watson test is for identifying if there is any autocorrelation in your data. If you want to estimate the number of seasons, you should perform seasonal decomposition and take a look at a spectral density plot. You can do all of this with `proc timeseries`.